# What is the different between this, 'Statements in Highest 5 Percent by Runtime' from the Performance Report and slow query log?

Tags: mysql

1. What is  'Statements in Highest 5 Percent by Runtime' from the Performance Report MySQL?
2. How is this different from the slow query log?
3. Do I need to pay attention to the query log in the 'Statements in Highest 5 Percent by Runtime'?
4. Does the query in this 'Statements in Highest 5 Percent by Runtime' means the query is a bad query?

Can anyone explain on this?

Comment: anyone please help me

Comment: please help meeeee